# JOptionPane to JCombobox or combine them if possible.?

Tags: java, swing, oop, jcombobox, joptionpane

My friend created a bank/ATM transaction program. It allows the user to deposit, withdraw and check the balance. But the problem is, it does not allow the user to choose what transaction he/she wants to do, it always asks the user to deposit first before he/she can withdraw or check the balance AGAIN. So i got an idea to offer a combobox, but my other problem is i don't know how to do it because I'm just a beginner in Java programming.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class atm {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        while(true){
        String intro = "Welcome to ATM Transactions";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,intro);
        String number1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the amount to deposit:");
        String number2 = "The amount deposited is:" + number1;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,number2);
        String number3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the amount to withdraw:");
        int number4 = (Integer.parseInt(number1)) - (Integer.parseInt(number3));
        String answer = "The remaining balance is:" +number4;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,answer);
        String[] choices = {"Yes", "No"};
        int response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Do you want another 
transactions?","Question",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,null,choices,"No");
        if (response==1)
            System.exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

So my question is, how to make this into a combobox so that the user can choose what transaction he/she wants to perform and also the user can do multiple deposits or withdrawals without going through the first step?

Comment: Given this is apparently homework, and the questions indicate you have skipped the early parts (e.g. exercises & homework) of the course, my advice is..  Go back and do those parts and the answer to your questions will become more clear.  Or at least your questions will become more specific.  As it is, voting to close as 'too broad'.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the [full-featured `JOptionPane` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#JOptionPane%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object%29)? It will allow you to include several buttons in a dialog, which might be more a appropriate user interface for your case.

Answer (score 2):

To include a `JComboBox` in a `JOptionPane` dialog, you have to treat it as the `message` property of the dialog. According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html), the `message` may, among others, be a `Component`, which is then displayed in the dialog. You can query the selected value of the dropdown list after the dialog was confirmed and control returnes to your code.